# App Inventor 2 files not showing up in assets folder on phone

Tags: android, assets, app-inventor

I have been trying to get my `webview` to show a local html file, but when I open it on my phone it says the file isn't there.

When I open the `.aia` file on my laptop the file is in the /assets folder.

Anyone else has this problem and has been able to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue on a Google Pixel phone. I have tried using the file paths suggested by @Taifun below and it does not solve the problem. Did you have any luck with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you also can upload html files as assets into App Inventor! There is only one special thing to consider: During development, you have to use the development path to the embedded html document:

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/AppInventor/assets/<NAME OF YOUR HTML FILE>.html
```

Before building the app, use the production path.

```
file:///android_asset/<NAME OF YOUR HTML FILE>.html
```

See some examples [here](https://puravidaapps.com/tutorials.php#html)

Comment: these file paths no longer work in 2020. Is there an update?